# Page is unresponsive till the widget completes downloading of js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

We have added a widget on the Master Page and what we have observed is that the page remains unresponsive till the time the widget downloads required scripts and HTML markups.
This behaviour is very prominent in IE 8.

I am using the following code to load the script.

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptTag.async = true;
scriptTag.src = amigoSrc;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptTag, s);
```

Is there any other approach that we can use to overcome this issue?

Comment: where does this code appear in your document?

Comment: Bottom of the Master Page after the form closing tag.

Comment: Async is not support in IE9 and earlier. Perhaps try just `document.write('<script src="path" />')` to see if it makes a diff.

Comment: Papa,
Tried removing async,and it is the same,no difference.